# Construction of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

In our lecture notes of Algebra, we have the following construction:

> Let $K$ be a field and $P \in K[X]$ be irreducible and monic. Let $L := K[X]/(P)$ and $a:=X+(P)$. Then, $L=K(a)$ is a field extension of $K$ and $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$.

I am slightly confused by the definition of $a$. Isn't $a$ supposed to be an element of $L$? We define $a := X + (P)$ so basically we add a variable $X$ and an ideal $(P)$ to each other? What is the meaning of this addition?

As an example, we are given $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$. So in this case, $P = X^2 +1$. What is $a$? By above definition, it should be $a = X + (X^2+1)$, right?

Did I just make a mistake in my lecture notes or is $a$ really supposed to be defined like this?

Comment: Do you know what a *quotient ring* is? You **must** know and understand clearly what this algebraic construction is in order to understand that what you were given is just fine and sound...

Comment: Just after submitting this question, it came to my mind that in the definition $a:=X+(P)$, the $X$ is probably not meant as a variable, but as the polynomial $X \in K[X]$, right?

Comment: Right. So $a$ is the residue class of $X \in K[X]$ modulo $P$.

Comment: $\,X\,$ is used both as the variable of the polynomials and as the polynomial itself. The elements in $\,K[X]/(P)\,$ are of the form $\,g(X)+(P)\;$ , with $\,g(X)\in K[X]\;$ ...

Comment: I see. The use of $X$ as both a variable and a polynomial caused the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is, what is $K[X]/(P)$? Or more generally, given a ring $R$ and and ideal $I$ of $R$, what is $R/I$?

$R/I$ is the set of cosets $r + I$, for $r \in R$. So $R/I = \{ r + I : r \in R \}$.

In turn, $r + I$ is defined as $\{ r + u : u \in I\}$. (One could see that the $r+ I$ are the equivalence classes of the relation on $R$ given by $r \sim s$ if and only if $r - s \in I$.)

$R/I$ becomes a ring defining
$$
(r + I) + (s + I) = (r+s) + I,\quad\text{and}\quad
(r + I) \cdot (s + I) = (rs) + I.
$$

In this case $I = (P)$ is the principal ideal generated by $P$, so $(P) = \{ P Q : Q \in K[X] \}$.

Comment: Nicely illustration. +1